# Receive Map in ktor server using kotlinx.serialization

Tags: json, dictionary, kotlin, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

I have a Ktor server running with kotlinx.serialization as it's json (de)serializer
I send my Ktor a message like this one:

```
{
  "Brick(partNumber=004229, partName=Sticker Sheet for Set 295-1, dataSource=Rebrickable, brickImage=null, categoryID=58)": 5
}
```

which is a pair of an Int and this class:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Brick(
    val partNumber: String,
    val partName: String,
    val dataSource: String,
    val brickImage: String?,
    val categoryID: Int?
)
```

But I get this error

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonDecodingException: Invalid JSON at 0: Expected '[, kind: MAP'
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonReader.fail(JsonReader.kt:293)
```

Which to me means that kotlinx.serialization expects a different syntax for the map class. Which is odd to me. When I change the type into List> it throws the same exception but with LIST instead of MAP.
EDIT: Upon further inspection, it expects a [ instead of a { at the start of the line.
My (partial) application implementation

```kotlin
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) { serialization() }
    routing {
        route("user") {
            route("brick") {
                post {
                    call.request.queryParameters["userName"]
                        ?.let { userRepository.login(it) } // Someone else is still working login nvm this
                        ?.let { user ->
                            val bricks = call.receive<Map<Brick, Int>>() // This throws an error
                            userRepository.addBricks(user, bricks)
                            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        }
                        ?: call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The android retrofit function that sends the class (using GSON):

```kotlin
    @POST("/user/brick")
    suspend fun setBricksAmounts(
        @Query("userName")
        userName: String,
        @Body
        brickAmounts: Map<Brick, Int>
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using a class as a key does not work in kotlinx serialization
and it looks like that class is just serialized into a string to use it as key

Instead you can receive it as `Map<String, Int>`
and afterwards run

```
bricks.mapKeys { (jsonString, number) ->
   Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable).parse(Brick.Serializer, jsonString)
}
```

or the equivalent jackson code if you want